# Methods DZ.player.getCurrentTrack() and DZ.player.getCurrentIndex() not working properly on Javascript SDK

Tags: deezer

I'm trying to get the current song every 500ms from the player so I can update my queue, however, when I use the DZ.player.addToQueue method it changes both currentIndex and currentTrack to the first song back again. While the player keeps on the right song without changing it, the index goes back to the first one until the current song ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed in the latest version; the index will not go back to the first song.